# Firebase data Structure

Tags: firebase

Im trying to develop little todo app using firebase and angular. Im struggling a bit with the structure of the data since Im not used of not dealing with arrays. 
[image: Firebase structure]

The "random letters" are the unique id generated by $push() in firebase. Would this be a correct way of structuring my data in firebase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "the correct way", unless we go through all of your use-cases. That said: your approach sounds reasonable.

I would make one change thought and change your data structure to:

```
{
  "lists": {
    "jhgyftdr": {
      "feref3f344f":"Item 1",
      "fewfw4":"Item 2"
    }
  },
  "users":{
    "user1":{
      "name":"john doe"
      "lists":
        "jhgyftdr": true
    }
  }
}
```

So this simply uses the (`push`-generated) `name()` under `users` -> `lists`.

With this structure you could load the lists for a user with something like this:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://your.firebaseio.com/');

ref.child('users/user1/lists').on('value', function(lists) {
  lists.forEach(function(listSnapshot) {
    ref.child('lists/'+listSnapshot.name()).once('value', function(listSnapshot) {
      console.log(listSnapshot.val());
    });
  });
});
```

*Please don't include screenshots of text. I had to now go and capture your data; time which I could've spent answering questions.*

Comment: thank you! sorry for that, didn't know. Yes I was reading a bit more and understand the fact that the value = true, doesn't really serves any purpose because i want the key. again thank you.

Comment: A follow up question: The structure you recommended assumes the order in which the lists are added to /users/user1/lists doesn't matter right? Suppose I wanted to display the user's list in the order they were added, then would the OP's original structure be better?